# I'm trying to make a welcome message using a JSON set channel but it's not working

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a welcome message using `on_member_join` but it doesn't work. Here's all the code that I think is related to the issue:

My imports

```
#Imports
import discord
import random
import os
import keep_alive
import requests
import json
from Variables import *
from discord.ext import commands
```

Everything related to the welcome message:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('guilds.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        guilds_dict = json.load(f)

    channel_id = guilds_dict[str(member.guild.id)]
    await client.get_channel(int(channel_id)).send(f'{member.mention} welcome to the Otay! Support server! Enjoy your stay!')


@client.command(name='welcome')
async def set_welcome_channel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    with open('guilds.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        guilds_dict = json.load(f)

    guilds_dict[str(ctx.guild.id)] = str(channel.id)
    with open('guilds.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(guilds_dict, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
    
    await ctx.send(f'Sent welcome channel for {ctx.message.guild.name} to {channel.name}')
```

Inside the JSON file called "guilds.json"

```
{
    "822514664863957054": "847897881431900222"
}
```

My friend did the exact same thing but it worked for him, so I'm very confused. Please comment on this message if you want any more information.

Any support would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: do you have the membres Intent activated? ([Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#where-d-my-members-go))

Comment: I tried to add that but it gave me an error message. I didn't think it was needed.

Comment: if you want the `on_member_join` to work, you need the member Intent ;)

Comment: intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bottoken = os.environ['BotToken']
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="d", intents = intents,  incasesensitive=True)

Comment: I did that and I got an error:

Comment: raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.

Comment: as the error says: you need to activate them in the [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), again see the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents)

Comment: Okay thankyou Guddi for the support it now works. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this below the imports

`intents = discord.Intents.default()`

`intents.members = True`

And put this - intents=intents below

`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'd', intents = intents)`

On the developers page https://discord.com/developers/applications go to your application and on to the bot part in the sidebar [click on the bot part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lozgu.jpg)

Look at this image and make sure the highlighted bits are checked
[make sure the highlighted bits in yellow are checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IKKv.jpg)

Hopefully this worked

Comment: I'm not getting the error anymore I will see if the welcome message works.

Comment: Okay, thankyou you couldv'e just told me when we were trying to get it to work lol

Comment: Huh i want reputation so i can comment

Comment: Well i have ur discord tag

Comment: And I’m friends with u i think

Comment: Wait i know u irl